# Custom sort of keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, sorting, key-value

I have a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` with following entries:

```
[adress_first_name, Andreas]
[adress_last_name, Test]
[adress_street, Berlinerstraße 2]
[adress_street_name, Berlinerstraße]
[adress_street_number, 2]
**[adress_street2, Tür 5]**
[adress_zipcode, 4600]
```

unfortunatly, the right order must be

```
[adress_first_name, Andreas]
[adress_last_name, Test]
[adress_street, Berlinerstraße 2]
**[adress_street2, Tür 5]**
[adress_street_name, Berlinerstraße]
[adress_street_number, 2]
[adress_zipcode, 4600]
```

Because of an external partner (who signs this list, and we need to verify the signature to make sure nothing has been manipulated with) the sort order must be like the second example.

What is the best way to do this using Linq? Of course, there are others, in that order. street2 is not the only example.

[image: 1]

at the moment I order the list like here

[image: 2]

Comment: That looks like a collection of `KeyValuePair<string,string>`. What type is the collection, and how is it being sorted now?

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks. It's beeing sortet by .OrderBy(kv => kv.Key) (i added a picture to the post)

Comment: Then you need to implement a custom sort that knows all your key constants used here and can put them in the right order. Presumably replace OrderBy by your custom Extension method.

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks, thats a simple and perfect solution for my problem.

Comment: For the future, it's more helpful to paste your code into your question than to use a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First order them by making address and address2 the same, then order by the key natural to split the tie:

```
.OrderBy(kv => (kv.Key.TrimEnd('2'), kv.Key))
```

This utilizes tuples sorting by all properties in order of appearance

You can also use the long form:

```
.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key.TrimEnd('2')).ThenBy(kv => kv.Key)
```

If you have more (address3, 4, 5..) you can add those to the trim. If you breach 9 and go to address10 you can OrderBy the trim of all numbers, then the Length of the key (so 9 sorts before 10), then the key itself to sort the numbers

Comment: thanks a lot. simple and useful solution for my problem.

Comment: Your code does not work for `{ "adress_street3", "Tür 5" }`

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper thats right, for my problem it's fine and the fastest solution

Comment: @Hochzeit.Management, I didn't say it is slow. If there is a key `"adress_street3"` then this query will not sort your items the way you explained.

Comment: It also doesn't calculate Pi to 400  decimal places or format the hard disk but those things, like address3, were not in the specification.. There is a comment at the end on how it might be adjusted for other scenarios but we can only answer questions as posed; it's unnecessary and illogical to write enterprise-fizzbuz for every answer

Answer (score 0):

Use ordinal string comparer.

```
.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```